# How to specify the model type to be used in R package eHOF?

Tags: r, regression, modeling

I can't figure out how to specify the model type in package eHOF (I want to plot a model other than the one chosen by the program). I create a HOF object:

```
sg.hof <- HOF(SG_Pres, logdtw, M=1, family=binomial, bootstrap=NULL)
```

This fits the seven hierarchical regression models, and works fine, but let's say the program chooses model VI as being the best, but I want to use model III instead, how do I plot model III? I thought something like this would work, but it doesn't:

```
plot(sg.hof, para=TRUE, model=3)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score -1):

```
plot(sg.hof, para=TRUE, model='III')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting an answer. While code only answers are answers, please consider expanding your post to include an explanation about your code.